# How to get Protocol column value in Wireshark dissector?

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have wrote a plugin to analyze (translate to different Protocol name) packet in Wireshark with LUA APIs. All I needed to do to only analyze packets that shows UDP or TCP in Wireshark. I am using that following code to get protocol value:
pinfo.cols.protocol
to only analyze the packets that will show as TCP or UDP in Protocol column.

Sometime it retrains the value that is in Protocol column (e.g. TCP, SSH, or ...) but most of the time it returns "(protocol)".

How can I fix it? Is there any way possible that I can figure it out?

Thanks